# Is adding (or removing) a null event listener a no-op?

Tags: c#, events, null, event-handling

Usually answers to questions like this can be found either here or, if not here, on MSDN, but I have looked and looked and not found the answer.  Experimentation seems to show that code like:

```
SomeControl.Click += null;
```

does no harm.  Or at least that firing the event doesn't toss an exception (that I can tell) by trying to invoke a null event listener.  However, there seems to be nowhere on the Web that will validate my hope that such code isn't doing at least *something* that I might not want done.  For example, causing the Click event to think it has listeners when it might not, and wasting those ever-precious super-ultra-mini-microseconds in "now let's perform null-checks and invoke all listeners that are not null" code.

It seems that documentation should say what the behavior of the += and -= operators is if the listener on the RHS is null.  But like I say, I can't find that documentation anywhere.  I'm sure someone here can provide it, though....

(Obviously, my code doesn't have a hard-coded null; my question is more about whether code like this is wasteful or completely harmless:

```
public static void AddHandlers([NotNull] this Button button,
                               [CanBeNull] EventHandler click = null,
                               [CanBeNull] EventHandler load = null)
{
    button.Click += click;
    button.Load += load;
}
```

or if I should [i.e., *need* to for any reason] add null-checks around each such += operation.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.Blah += Qaz;
    foo.Blah += null;
    foo.OnBlah();
}

public void Qaz()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Qaz");
}

public class Foo
{
    public event Action Blah;
    public void OnBlah()
    {
        var b = Blah;
        if (b != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calling Blah");
            b();
            Console.WriteLine("Called Blah");
        }
    }
}
```

As is it runs without error and produces the following output:

```
Calling Blah
Qaz
Called Blah
```

If I remove the line `foo.Blah += Qaz;` then the code runs without error, but produces no output, so the `null` handler is effectively ignored.

As far as IL goes, the line `foo.Blah += null;` produces the following IL:

```
IL_001A:  ldloc.0     // foo
IL_001B:  ldnull      
IL_001C:  callvirt    Foo.add_Blah
IL_0021:  nop
```

So, it behaves as a `nop`, but it clearly runs the code.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have thought of trying that!

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on whether the `+=` (or `-=`) operator is being applied to an *event* or a *delegate*.

In your `AddHandlers` example, the `Button` class probably defines `Click` and `Load` as events, not delegates. When its left operand is an event, the `+=` operator simply invokes the `add` accessor of the event without any additional null checks. That is, under the covers `button.Click += value;` is just a method call:

```
button.add_Click(value);
```

Like any other method, how `add_Click` deals with a null argument is entirely up to the `Button` class.

Now consider how the `Button` class might actually implement the `Click` event. Here's one way:

```
private EventHandler _click;
public event EventHandler Click
{
    add { _click += value; }
    remove { _click -= value; }
}

// Or even shorter...
// public event EventHandler Click;
// ... which is the same as above plus extra stuff for thread safety.
```

In this implementation, [`EventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) is a delegate type. When both operands are delegates, the `+=` operator invokes [`Delegate.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30cyx32c(v=vs.110).aspx). The documentation says that `Delegate.Combine(a, b)` returns:

> A new delegate with an invocation list that concatenates the invocation lists of *a* and *b* in that order. Returns *a* if *b* is **null**, returns *b* if *a* is a null reference, and returns a null reference if both *a* and *b* are null references.

Conclusion: As long as the `Button` class implements its events in the "standard" way (rather than, say, keeping track of listeners in an explicit `List<EventHandler>`), then `button.Click += null;` will ultimately *not* add a null listener.